# How to specify a connection point for an element in which connectors can link there in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

It's possible to define a shape for a stereotype in Enterprise Architect. How is it possible to specify an exact point on that shape to link incoming/outgoing connectors?

For example, connectors can be linked to a "Gateway" only on its corners, not to any other position on the edges. How are those corners defined as the only entry/exit point?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. I'm not aware of any shape script properties you can set to achieve this.

The BPMN Gateway is a stereotyped UML Decision, and the connectors-at-corners-only behaviour is inherited from that (you can test this in a regular Activity diagram). I think EA handles these differently from other elements in a way which cannot be controlled from a shape script.

Of course, you can always create your own Decision stereotype and get the same result, but semantically that might not be what you're after.